# DParser- warning: trying to write code to binary file

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, parser-generator, glr

I have a large grammar written for [DParser](http://dparser.sourceforge.net/) and using the Python binding.  When I first run the parser, and DParser generates its internal tables, I get a number of warnings like these:

```
warning: trying to write code to binary file
warning: trying to write code to binary file
warning: trying to write code to binary file
```

Not sure what the cause of source of these warnings are.  The only thing I could find was in the DParser source code "write_tables.c":

```c
write_code(FILE *fp, Grammar *g, Rule *r, char *code,
           char *fname, int line, char *pathname) 
{
    char *c;

    if ( !fp ) {
        d_warn("trying to write code to binary file");
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Any hints or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say you didn't give Dparser a file name in which to write its generated tables.  Did you read its usage docs?

Comment: Of course I have read the docs.  The file name for the tables are automatically chosen (d_parser_mach_gen.g.d_parser.dat, d_parser_mach_gen.g.md5).  I found out that the problem with these warnings was because I had errors in my grammar and I had forgot to add quotes around [ ] in some cases.  Like [ example_non_terminal ].  It was taking example_non_terminal as a character set.  A number of these were causing the problem.

Comment: You might add your discovery of the problem as an answer (yes, you can answer your own question) so this question achieves closure.  [I have to admit, the causal connection between failing to quote a grammar element and the error message you got, completely escapes me].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem with these warnings was because I had errors in my grammar and I had forgotten to add quotes around [ ] in some cases.  Like:

```
 [ example_non_terminal ]
```

It was taking example_non_terminal as a character set.  A number of these were causing the problem.  The correct grammar should have been:

```
 '[' example_non_terminal ']'
```